# Browsers can't pick up the mic after upgrade

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

After I did `sudo apt upgrade`, no browser can detect the microphone any longer on my Xubuntu 16.04.06 LTS. The only option in the dropdown menu is "None available" (the only exception is Firefox, it picks up Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo)

The microphone actually works, and it is listed as `Built-in Audio Analog Stereo` **Port:**`Front Microphone (unplugged)` in Volume Control. Nothing changed there, this is exactly how it was listed before.

If I enable my webcam mic, which is listed as `Webcam C250 Analog Mono` **Port:**`Microphone`, the browsers can detect it, but that's not what I need.

It's just the browsers, Viber, for instance, can use the front mic with no problems whatsoever.

`pacmd`'s output:

```
$ pacmd
Welcome to PulseAudio 8.0! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> list-sources
3 source(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 1950
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max rewind: 17 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    fixed latency: 99,95 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    card: 2 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 8
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd2140000 irq 131"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a170"
        device.product.name = "Sunrise Point-H HD Audio"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
  * index: 1
    name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9959
    volume: front-left: 65540 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65540 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 6554 /  10% / -60,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,44 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    fixed latency: 99,95 ms
    card: 2 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC887-VD Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC887-VD Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd2140000 irq 131"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a170"
        device.product.name = "Sunrise Point-H HD Audio"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "17632"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "4408"
        device.access_mode = "mmap"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC887-VD"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0887,104386c7,00100302 HDA:80862809,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:

    active port: <analog-input-front-mic>
    index: 4
    name: <alsa_input.usb-046d_0804_12B9C590-02.analog-mono>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9049
    volume: mono: 65535 / 100% / -0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 20724 /  32% / -30,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,49 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 1ch 48000Hz
    channel map: mono
                 Mono
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    fixed latency: 99,94 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.usb-046d_0804_12B9C590-02>
    module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "USB Device 0x46d:0x804"
        alsa.long_card_name = "USB Device 0x46d:0x804 at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-046d_0804_12B9C590-02"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "046d"
        device.vendor.name = "Logitech, Inc."
        device.product.id = "0804"
        device.product.name = "Webcam C250"
        device.serial = "046d_0804_12B9C590"
        device.form_factor = "webcam"
        device.string = "hw:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "9594"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "2398"
        device.access_mode = "mmap"
        device.profile.name = "analog-mono"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Mono"
        device.description = "Webcam C250 Analog Mono"
        alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
        alsa.components = "USB046d:0804"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    active port: <analog-input-mic>
>>>
```

UPD. Perhaps if I could force-set Front Microphone as plugged that would solve the problem. But I can't figure out a way to do that. Jack detection never did work for the front jacks on my desktop. The system always detected the rear jacks smoothly, but never the front jacks.

UPD2. I've installed `alsa-tools-gui`, and overrode jack detection to inverse. That helped, but it's just a workaround. I hope there's something more permanent.

Comment: does unplugging the mic, then rebooting, then plugging it into a different usb port do anything? is it a usb mic? does installing `pavucontrols` and `paprefs` and messing with their individuals configurations solve this?

Comment: No, it's not a USB mic, it's an analog headset mic (but the headset has 2 3.5mm jacks rather than one so the system treats it as two separate devices). The mic worked but it was not detected as plugged in, and I suspect that the newest upgrade prevented the browsers and maybe some other programs from picking up "unplugged" devices that are actually plugged-in and live.

Comment: ok what about that paprefs and pavucontrols? also could you include a screenshot of your current output and input settings?

Comment: I've been using pavucontrol for years now, and it always listed the mic as unplugged, but the mic was working despite that. I've install paprefs, but I can't see how it can be helpful because from what I gather it mostly deals with networks. _I've found a temp workaround (see UPD2) to my problem, but that's just that, a workaround and not a solution._

Comment: oh so you made the mic function correctly again with `alsa-tools-gui`? is this bothersome because you have to do the overriding at every boot or just because the solution is "unclean"?

Comment: The latter, actually, because I learned from experience that such unclean solutions may bring down a service one day or just stop working - and after they do, I have to start over with trying to understand what the problem is.